# How to stop user from clicking any other button while page is refreshing (a part from Modal window solution)

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, onchange

I am looking for a solution where on a select box if user selects
a item, the page refreshes with updated data.This is done using 
`onChange` function. In the meanwhile if user clicks on `submit` and then `reset` button whatever changes made were reset because the subit is not happened after `onChange`.

One solution I thought is bringing up the modal window when
`onChange` function is called but it involves a lot of work for processing

So I am looking if there is any alternate to this

Comment: Disable those buttons when onchange is called and re enable them when page is loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go down the modal and/or overlay route, it's a nicer user experience as the user can see that something is happening. Simplest solution is just stick a div somewhere on the page

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

and add some css:

```
#overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index:10;
    position:fixed;
    display:none;
}
```

NB: opacity doesn't work in IE 8 and older, but there are alternatives that a quick Google will uncover.

Then in your onChange (assuming your using jQuery) just put a $('#overlay').show() or .fadeIn(), and either hide it when complete or if the page refreshes there no need to do anything.

If you don't want anything visible take out the background-color and opacity and it will be invisible.

I would recommend sticking a loading gif in the middle of #overlay for the sake of clarity.

Hope that helps.

Comment: :this seems to be a clean solution.How do I call this div on normal javascript

Comment: Normal javascript? why would you do that to yourself :p but it can be done pretty easily with document.getElementById('overlay').style.visibility = 'visible';

Comment: wait ... sorry that doesn't work with the display none, you'd need document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block'; and display='none' again to hide.

Comment: +1 Yes, I thought in a css trick like this too. It should works very well.

Answer (score 3):

disable the buttons in the method which is called in onchange. Then on page load enable them back.

```
function onChangefunc()
{
  document.getElementById("button1").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("button2").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("button3").disabled = true;

  // do rest of your logic here  
}
```

Then place this at the end of the page in  tag:

```
  <script>
  document.getElementById("button1").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("button2").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("button3").disabled = false;
  </script>
```

Comment: Your answer `disable the buttons in the method which is called in onchange. Then on page load enable them back.` is almost exactly the same that kishore gave before. Could you contribute something new like some code to represent your answer?